# Set vim filetype script for c++ headers only

Tags: c++, vim

I basically want to have `vim` use a command on c++ header files, and only on c++ header files.  How can I do this?

I have tried putting the commands in `~/.vim/ftplugin/hpp.vim` to no avail as the hpp files are seen as cpp files by Vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `~/.vim/ftplugin/cpp.vim`:

```
if expand('%:e') ==? 'hpp'
    " your script here
endif
```

Better yet:

```
if expand('%:e') =~? '\v^h%(pp|h|\+\+|xx)?$'
    " your script here
endif
```

Comment: don't forget .hh which is the pendant of .cc also used for C++.
also how does vim detect the language on files without extension?

Comment: @FelixBytow Edited, thank you.  The extension is only one way to determine the filetype, looking at the beginning of the file is another.  There are other ways, too.  See the the file `filetype.vim` in the runtime directory if you're curious.

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
autocmd BufEnter *.hpp :setlocal filetype=hpp
```

to your vimrc

So that the filetype of your hpp files is recognized as hpp.

You can then use `~/.vim/ftplugin/hpp.vim` to put your specific commands

Comment: Your method works, but also removes the syntax highlighting.